# How to print python requests response in ansible

Tags: python, ansible, python-requests

Hi I am running python script using ansible which prints json response after getting data from url.
How can I see json output after running ansible task (In ansible output)?

Here is my playbook

```
----
- name: Run on remote host
hosts: localhost

tasks:
 - name: run python script locally
command: python test.py -argument1 value -argument value
```

and this my python script

```
import pprint
import requests
import base64

pat = ""
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')),   
'ascii')
url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1"

headers = {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
   print('Success!')
elif response.status_code == 404:
   print('Not Found.')
data = response.json()
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Comment: start with storing  it to some register in the task where you are running command

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables

Comment: furthermore, based solely upon what you've posted you can use the ansible [`uri:` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) to [`return_content: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-return_content), along with the helpful `register:` that was already suggested